# Examples of great mathematical writing

Tags: mathematical-writing, soft-question, big-list

This question is basically from [Ravi Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/)'s web page, but modified for Math Overflow.

*How do I write mathematics well?* Learning by example is more helpful than being told what to do, so let's try to name as many examples of "great writing" as possible. Asking for "the best article you've read" isn't reasonable or helpful. Instead, ask yourself the question "what is a great article?", and implicitly, "what makes it great?"

If you think of a piece of mathematical writing you think is "great", check if it's already on the list. If it is, vote it up. If not, add it, with an explanation of why you think it's great. This question is "Community Wiki", which means that the question (and all answers) generate no reputation for the person who posted it. It also means that once you have 100 reputation, you can edit the posts (e.g. add a blurb that doesn't fit in a comment about why a piece of writing is great). **Remember that each answer should be about a *single* piece of "great writing", and please restrict yourself to posting one answer per day.**

I refuse to give criteria for greatness; that's your job. But please don't propose writing that has a major flaw unless it is outweighed by some other truly outstanding qualities. In particular, "great writing" is not the same as "proof of a great theorem". You are not allowed to recommend anything by yourself, because you're such a great writer that it just wouldn't be fair.

Not acceptable reasons:

- This paper is really very good.
- This book is the only book covering this material in a reasonable way.
- This is the best article on this subject.

Acceptable reasons:

- This paper changed my life.
- This book inspired me to become a topologist. (Ideally in this case it should be a book in topology, not in real analysis...)
- Anyone in my field who hasn't read this paper has led an impoverished existence.
- I wish someone had told me about this paper when I was younger.

Comment: A useful feature of Math Overflow on a post like this one is the ability to sort answers chronologically as well as by number of votes. Just click the "newest" tab above the answers to see the most recent additions.

Comment: You write "I wish someone had told me about this paper when I was younger", lucky you :-) When I was young(er) I was unable to read papers, just books and even that was not obvious.

Answer (score 143):

Anything by John Milnor fits the bill. In particular, "Topology from the differential viewpoint" made me feel that I understand what differential topology is about, and the "h-cobordism theorem" made me feel that it's beautiful. Many other books and papers by him are wonderful; the first that come to mind are "Characteristic Classes", "Morse Theory", lots of things in Volume 3 of his collected papers.

Comment: "Characteristic Classes" is particularly great indeed, I do love most of Milnor's books.

Comment: I read Milnor's "Dynamics in One Complex Variable" as a graduate student -- it was wonderful.

Comment: This should be so much higher than Serre :-). One of the differences between the two is that writings of Milnor can be appreciated almost by a layman, whereas apparently Serre needs a reasonably educated mathematician to appreciate.

Comment: Milnor's writing is masterful. Morse Theory for example is a *fantastic* book -- the writing is smooth and clear, and the proofs are remarkably detailed and complete. A most satisfying read. 

Answer (score 95):

True story: When I was about to move to Stony Brook to start my PhD, one of my professors took me aside to tell me "You know, when I was a student Milnor was god, and *Morse Theory* was the bible." I found that nice and moved on, but a little later a younger professor took me aside to say "You know, when I was a student Milnor was god, and *Introduction to Algebraic K-Theory* was the bible." By then I knew that something was going on, but I was still taken by surprise when a more junior professor found me and said "You know, when I was a student Milnor was god, and *Characteristic Classes* was the bible."

Of course this was all planned. They succeeded in motivating me to take every opportunity to talk to and learn from the big names I met. But they made another point that I only recognized later, while writing my first paper: *If you want to learn to write Mathematics **well**, read anything by Milnor*.

When I was a student, *Dynamics in One Complex Variable* was the bible.

Answer (score 90):

Canonical submission: Anything by J.-P. Serre (e.g., Local Fields, Trees, Algebraic Groups and Class Fields,...).
Reasons:

- I can't get enough of Trees, chapter 2.  I spent a year working on automorphic forms on function fields in part because of this book (it didn't work out well, but that's another story).
- Peer pressure: several people (including my Ph.D. advisor) have told me that if I were to choose a role model for writing style, I should choose him.
- Mundane reasons: His writing is incredibly clear and concise, but not so brief as to be confusing.  He has a keen eye for what is important in a theory or construction.  He doesn't waste words having a conversation with the reader or expounding on his philosophy of mathematical practice.

Comment: Although my French is fairly weak, I was able to read and immensely enjoy Serre's "Cours d'Arithmetique". Clear, motivated, engaging and simply memorable.

"Trees" is incredible.

Comment: Oops, I guess I was supposed to submit a single piece.  I'd say "Oeuvres de Serre" but it doesn't contain his books.

Comment: There is a video of a talk he gave entitled something like "How to write bad mathematics" or rather write mathematics poorly, it is a fun talk to watch. 

Comment: When I first spotted this question, my mind immediately went to Serre's books. The 1st part of "Cours d'Arithmetique" is one of my main references for my introductory undergraduate course in Number Theory. I also used his book "Linear representation of finite groups" as textbook once. "Corps Locaux" is another great book. I also like to mention his fundamental papers "FAC" and "GAGA" which I greatly enjoyed reading back in my grad student days.

P.S.: I never read "Trees", but after reading Scott's answer, I feel a urge to do so! :-)

Comment: I haven't read Serre in years, but I remember that as an undergraduate his writing style was much too difficult, more precisely in my eyes your point 3 was not true. I specifically mean Trees, and more specifically definition of a graph.

Comment: My personal story: in my early years I always wanted too much. I wanted to read books which I would be only able to read after learning years' worth of further mathematics. In every single case I failed and had to give up after few first pages.  The only exception I remember was "Groupes algébriques et corps de classes". It is so incredibly well written that I was able to at least understand what's going on. I vividly remember feeling of ave. How on earth can this man achieve to make even guys like I was then to understand?!

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski Precisely one is not likely to go into Serre's "*Arbres, amalgames and* $\mathrm{SL}_2$" (or its English translation "*Trees*") just to have the definition of a graph. But to have the definition of the Bass-Serre fundamental group of a "graph of groups". To define this, a precise formal definition of a graph (with source and target maps etc) are necessary, and not just idle formalism. The bare notion of Bass-Serre fundamental group of a graph of groups is possibly hard for an undergraduate.

Answer (score 65):

The book of Bott-Tu "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" was my door to enter the magic world of cohomology, Chern classes and similar topics. Moreover, it contains a wonderful (and in my opinion the best) exposition of spectral sequences with applications to the computation of some higher homotopy groups of the sphere. All that is presented in a self-contained way and in a magnificent style. A masterpiece!

Comment: I completely agree with you! In my opinion that is one of the best books ever!

Answer (score 59):

Real Analysis by Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi

I absolutely hated analysis until I read the Stein/Shakarchi analysis series (Fourier, Complex, Real Analysis). Now I find the subject to be very beautiful and full of deep ideas, and it is these books that really convinced me.

Comment: Agreed.  These books are very clearly written and motivate the subject well.

Comment: Thirded. This series immediately came to mind when I saw this question. 

Comment: Agreed further; in my opinion all three books of the series are "great mathematical writing".

Comment: Agree, this is what I wished for (and got) last christmas.

Comment: There are four books in the series.

Answer (score 57):

Michael Spivak's [Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0914098918) made me want to study analysis.

Comment: I learned calculus out of that book. It convinced me to become a math major ...

Comment: I'm reading Spivak now as a high school junior - it has inspired me to become a math major.

Comment: can you give an example of Spivak's book that shows why it is amazing? (I know he is great in all aspects).

Answer (score 52):

John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. This book reminded me of all the mathematics I kinda learned in undergrad, prepared me for graduate school, and taught me differential topology. I feel like every undergrad should have this book and work through it on their own.

Comment: Not just undergraduates ... and not just mathematicians ... can enjoy reading Lee's fine text.

Comment: I second this, absolute classic.

Answer (score 52):

I think Algebraic Topology by Hatcher is one of my early favourites. It starts off being very basic but it manages to mention so much fascinating stuff, and I think the exposition is great. Definitely inspired me and got me interested in algebraic topology.

His book in progress "Vector Bundles and Characteristic Classes" is also very nice.

Comment: His notes on three-manifolds are very pretty.  

Comment: Everybody who wants to learn about the Serre spectral sequence should also not waste his time with McCleary or something like this but turn to Hatcher's notes. 

Comment: I've personally always found this text way too verbose. Not to the point. It's very hard to read quickly or to find things.

Answer (score 51):

Just like in this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/which-mathematicians-have-influenced-you-the-most), I am amazed that no one mentions Deligne. I think it was Illusie who said Grothendieck had a gift to build new theories and new language while Serre's talent was to find new things to do with old tools. Deligne got  the generality, abstraction and theory building from Grothendieck and the clarity of exposition and the constant reference to older language/simple ideas from Serre. I think that's why he is sometimes overshadowed by his elders when someone asks this kind of question.

Here's a few examples. His "Théorie de Hodge I" explains the "yoga of weights" in just a few pages. The first sections of "[La conjecture de Weil I](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1974__43__273_0)" provide a great survey of both the theory of étale cohomology and Lefschetz theory for algebraic varieties almost from scratch. Another masterpiece is his "[Le groupe fondamental de la droite moins trois points](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9649-9_3)" where he builds a whole theory unifying several aspects of arithmetics, topology and differential equations but always comes back to very down to earth examples. Not to mention, his Bourbaki lectures or the uncountable number of private communications of his cited in the literature.

If you are looking for great examples of mathematical writing, you should definitely read some articles by Deligne.

Comment: I second, third and double second this!

Comment: I second Pera's comment.

Answer (score 50):

Walter Rudin's  *Real and Complex Analysis* has long been one of my favorites.  Like Serre, Rudin seems to strike a nice balance for detail, and his proofs are always slick and fun to read; I became heavily interested in analysis after reading that one.

Comment: @Akhil: please split this into multiple answers. The point of having a big list with **one answer per post** is that it makes it easy to vote things up and down. If you post more than one answer per post, this advantage of being able to bubble answers up and down is lost.

Comment: Sorry about that- I ought to have read the post more carefully.  I will fix it.

Comment: Rudin's writing may be good and clear, but I'm not sure of his approach. Rudin's Book on Functional analysis is not what I would recommend a beginner. When I was an undergraduate, I self-thought myself functional analysis and this was the first book that I read. I must admit it was a torture for me back then, I wouldn't teach functional analysis starting with the abstract topological vector spaces.

Comment: I agree that _Functional Analysis_ is less fun to read as the others.

Comment: Although these comments are months old, I'd like to chime in anyways and say that a lot of the criticisms people have about Rudin's choice of topics sort of disappear when you take his books together as a 3 volume course. With that in mind, his choice for chapter 2 of his R&C Analysis, which presents the Riesz theorem as the way to construct measures, makes sense, because in his undergrad book he already spent a chapter building lebesgue measure on R^1. Likewise, his choices in Functional Analysis are justified by the chapters on Banach, Hilbert space, & Banach algebras in his R&C Analysis.

Comment: What about people who don't like his first book to start with? :-)

Comment: I strongly disagrees with this recommendation. 

Comment: Ever since Lakatos's Proofs and Refutations, Rudin's expository style has been something of a whipping boy for certain people. I'm not sure how much of it is deserved. You gotta give him *some* credit: his proofs are often elegant. 

Answer (score 41):

One of the math books I enjoy reading in most is Neukirch's book "Algebraic Number Theory". In my opinion, he presents the material beautifully and with a good degree of generality for a text book. Also, he manages to use language beautifully without losing mathematical rigor and without compromising clarity (this holds for the German version as well as for the English translation). When I have to look up some fact from algebraic number theory, Neukirch is usually the first book I try.

Answer (score 40):

I love Grothendieck's Tohoku paper.

Comment: Me too. A brilliant evergreen.

Answer (score 39):

Without a doubt, Arnold's  *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*   is the book most responsible for me  deciding to be a geometer.  Only some papers of Atiyah were able to replicate the feeling of awe I had  reading Arnold's classic as  an impressionable green undergrad.    Very few authors are able to convey to me the feeling of completely unconstrained  thinking as Arnold's writings  do. They continue to be the go to place whenever   if feel stuck or stale in my research.  A few pages  from  him  still do the trick: they  remind me why I became a mathematician.

Comment: I learned to read French because of Arnold's book. When I was an undergrad the library only had the Mir edition: Les méthodes mathématiques de la mécanique classique.  I'm still in love with this book. 

Comment: My favourite too.

Comment: In the same vein one could add the terrific book "Ergodic Problems of Classical Mechanics" by Arnold and Avez.

Answer (score 38):

I'm not sure whether "expository" writing counts, but I'll go with it anyway...

I don't think it would necessarily change the life of anybody who was already into mathematics enough to pay for it, but I very much wish the *Princeton Companion* had come out when I was younger. You don't get the chance to get your hands dirty with the details of any of the topics the PCM covers, but sometimes you're not looking to get your hands dirty, and there's not much else of any quality that can compare in terms of breadth.

Answer (score 35):

[Proofs from the Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=KvQr9l0wgf8C&lpg=PP1&dq=proofs%20from%20the%20book&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false), Martin Aigner, Günter M. Ziegler, 2000.

Anyone in [mathematics] who hasn't read this [book] has led an impoverished existence.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  I've never found the style of proofs in it particularly beautiful--they're all just little combinatorial tricks.

Comment: It was a big delusion for me as well. If there is a Book, I seriously doubt it contains any of these proofs.

Comment: Well, I think Joyal's proof of Cayley's theorem does belong in "The Book". That's a proof one could never forget. On the other hand, I've never been keen on Zagier's one-sentence proof of Fermat's two-squares theorem -- it's just not that memorable, even after one has worked through the details. 

Comment: @Andrea: probably you mean s/delusion/disappointment. As an Italian, I often make that mistake, too. :)

Comment: "Disillusion" might be the sought-after word.

Comment: This got the 2018 Steele prize for mathematical exposition. Eric Wofsey and Anderea are criticizing the choice of the title of the book, which is off-topic here I am afraid (since the question is about great mathematical writing not writing great mathematics).

Comment: Regarding the comment about Zagier's one-sentence proof of Fermat's two-squares, one might like to see the very visual, geometric explanation in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299696/) (and many of the other answers to that question also have interesting discussions of that proof).

Answer (score 34):

Éléments de géométrie algébrique (EGA) (full text available from [numdam](http://www.numdam.org)) continues to be an inspirational text for me. I wish I'd started reading it earlier.

It's come up in a few [other places](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2446/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne/2540#2540) here on MO. To quote [Jonathan Wise's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3041/the-importance-of-ega-and-sga-for-students-of-today/3102#3102) to another question,

> Virtually every page I've read of EGA/SGA has been useful to me, and almost every page I've skimmed I've later wished I'd read in more detail. The reputation for difficulty is, I think, unfounded. They are certainly abstract, but virtually every detail is present; in many ways, that makes EGA/SGA easier to read than other sources. Opening a volume and reading a sub-paragraph from the middle can be difficult because of all the back-references, but reading linearly can be very pleasant and rewarding. The French language may be a barrier for some, but one doesn't have to "learn French" to learn enough to understand EGA.

Comment: Great maths: yes. Great writing: no. If you want to know why a particular theorem is true, you have to go back to all the theorems that it builds upon. And then farther back. And farther back.

Answer (score 33):

Silverman and Tate's "Rational Points on Eliptic Curves."

Comment: My guess is you want this to go under "I wish someone had told me about this when I was younger."  I'd have to agree, at least for the first few chapters.

Comment: Actually someone did tell me about this when I was younger.  I read it after senior year of highschool and greatly enjoyed it.

Answer (score 33):

Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* got me interested in that area for some time, too.  The exposition is fun to read, with both motivation and rigorous proofs.

Comment: Did you mean "Rational points on elliptic curves" as Noah mentioned, or Silverman's book with the title you gave?

Comment: No, I meant _The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves._ I've also looked at the book Noah mentioned, but I found this one more enjoyable.

Comment: Yes, this book is great. I like "Advanced Topics In The Arithmetic Of Elliptic Curves" even more, I love the description of complex multiplication it has, especially with regards to Kronecker's Jugendtraum and class field theory.

Comment: I find the exposition confusing and unnecessarily long, due to the fact that he assumes that the reader has no previous knowledge of either algebraic geometry or group cohomology.

Comment: Also very nice: he keeps up a list of errata on his website, so this book really is a great book to learn from: http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/AEC/AECErrata.pdf

Answer (score 30):

Mumford's "The Red Book of Schemes and Varieties" was the first book trying to explain Grothendieck's new theory of schemes to the large public. It does this with a lot of examples from the 'real life' and even with drawings! It is far from complete, but it remains the best for communicating the love for the subject and for the clearness of the exposition. Another masterpiece!

Answer (score 27):

This is not an example of great mathematical writing, but definitely something to know and probably even more useful: Paul Halmos' brilliant essay "How to write mathematics", which you'll find for example at 
http://i11www.iti.kit.edu/~awolff/lehre/scientific_writing/h-hwm-70.pdf.

Comment: Personally, I don't like this article.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński I like it. You might not agree with everything he says (Halmos knows you won't, and even says so), but there's a lot of good advice in there *and* he not only talks the talk, but walks the walk.  Care to say why you don't like it?

Comment: I like Halmos comment that there should be *one* topic in a writing. Sometimes that's unfeasible, but I feel that it is a sensible point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 26):

Gowers' *[Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780192853615.do)*.  This is in Oxford's series of "very short introductions" on a variety of topics (hieroglyphics, film, Rousseau,...), each of which I think is a tremendous challenge to the (invariably eminent) writer.  Gowers dispenses with "anecdotes, cartoons, exclamation marks, jokey chapter titles," and instead plunges right into details without apology.  The chapter on proofs is especially important for nonmathematicians to understand.  The explanations of concepts (e.g., "dimension") are lucid, achieving clarity without compromising on technical accuracy.
I read it in one sitting, which may dismay the author who must have labored over these small 160 pages, but which is a testimony of how smoothly he conveys his insights.

Comment: I totally agree. +1

Comment: Also, perhaps, "Mathematics: A Very Long Introduction". (This is what I call *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics*, of which Gowers was editor.)

Comment: I like this book, but despite several attempts, I've yet to find a non-mathematician who 'gets it'.  I worry that it's not suitable for its target audience.

Answer (score 25):

Atiyah & Bott's paper "The Yang-Mills Equations on Riemann Surfaces" is probably the most satisfying thing I've read.  The writing is great, and the ideas are all cool.

Comment: Yes. This is a wonderful paper!

Answer (score 25):

How about Munkres [Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131816292)? This book certainly made me want to be a (point-set) topologist. Turns out I came along a bit late for that field, but I'm sure this book helped push me into algebraic topology. Anyway, Munkres is full of fantastic examples and pictures, it treats all the major aspects of the field, and it seems to be the most popular book for courses in point-set topology all over the US.

Comment: It's certainly written with a lot of pedagogical care and consideration and, I'd have to say, human warmth. I continue to consult it regularly.

Answer (score 22):

Gian-Carlo Rota's [On the foundations of combinatorial theory I: Theory of Möbius Functions](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00531932) is an eye-opening gem. The same is true of practically every paper in [Gian-Carlo Rota on Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817637133), so consider this post a vote for the entire book. (If I become a combinatorialist, it will be because of this book.)

Comment: +1: nice to see such strong +ve statements.

Comment: Qiaochu: you *are* a combinatorialist! :-) 

Comment: @Todd: I'm flattered. It feels wrong for me to label myself anything until I at least start graduate school. 

Answer (score 22):

"Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces" by Rick Miranda is one of my favorite books.  It is full of concrete examples and is full of very clear explanations for everything from the basics of Riemann surfaces and their projective embeddings though sheaf cohomology.  Also, it assumes little more than elementary complex analysis.

Answer (score 22):

I'm surprised that nobody's mentioned almost anything by Emil Artin.  His little monographs on Galois Theory and the Gamma Function are thrilling to read.  They are so clear, and use the minimum necessary (but not more -- to paraphrase Einstein) I found them inspiring.  Also his "Algebraic Numbers and Algebraic Functions" and "Geometric Algebra".

Another book, is G. H. Hardy's "Pure Mathematics".  That's the book that I really learned analysis from (when I told that to Pat Gallagher he exclaimed that I was really lucky) when I was in high school.  Reading that cemented my feeling that I wanted to be a mathematician.

Comment: Surely you mean "but not less", not "but not more"?

Comment: +1 for Artin. On the other hand, I had "Pure Mathematics" by Hardy years ago, but each of the three authors (three separate works, textbooks on Mathematical Analysis): Banach, Sierpiński, Kuratowski--were so much better(!).

Answer (score 22):

Every differential geometer should read at least the first two volumes of Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*. In particular, volume 2 is an absolute gem. Not only does it reprint (translations of) original papers by Gauss and Riemann, complete with very enlightening notes and commentary, but (if I remember correctly) Spivak presents about 5 or 6 different proofs that a Riemannian manifold is flat if and only if it is locally isometric to Euclidean space. This gives the reader the best, most intuitive grasp of the concept of curvature that I have seen anywhere. (I am a firm believer in learning by repetition...)

Comment: The other volumes are useful as well, even if you don't read all of the material (a likely situation, the one issue with the volumes is that they are long). For example volume 5 gives a useful geometric perspective on partial differential equations which is not always presented in PDE texts.

Answer (score 19):

Since you wanted to learn writing from examples:
J. Kock and I. Vainsencher's book "An Invitation to Quantum Cohomology" is wonderful reading, simply because of its incredibly friendly style. It gives you the feeling that the authors take you by the hand and lead you through their garden of wonders (always uphill of course).
The achievement of the book is to give you lots of intuition - for moduli stacks, strategies for proofs in enumerative geometry, the necessity of a virtual fundamental class, how generating functions work... 
This is something very difficult to do in mathematical writing - in this respect you could compare it to John Baez's blog, only that it is a longer, coherent book on a single subject.

Comment: One of the few books that I actually read from cover to cover. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Dror's paper [Khovanov's homology for tangles and cobordisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410495) is one of the papers I loved back when I hated all math papers.  In particular it's a paper that has a really good use of diagrams, a lot of papers use too few diagrams and suffer a lot for it.

Comment: Bar-Natan's papers in general tend to be well-written. 

Answer (score 18):

Paolo Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0* presents the usual algebra material with special emphasis on category theory and homological algebra. It's written in a somewhat informal style that spurs on the reader and motivates constructions really well. I found it much better than Hungerford (which is often touted as an example of good writing itself); it is responsible for my interest in algebra and  (the rudiments of) algebraic geometry.

Comment: There is an impressive uniformity to Aluffi's book. He makes almost everything seem simple, almost guessable.

Answer (score 17):

Van der Waerden's Algebra. I became a mathematician because of this book.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a way to get a decent copy of the original language version of this

Comment: I remember buying the first volume (Springer German 1954 edition) on ebay some time ago.

Answer (score 17):

Many of Atiyah's papers, especially those with Bott, are truly inspiring -- not only "The Yang-Mills Equations on Riemann Surfaces" but also "The Moment Map and Equivariant Cohomology" and "Convexity and Commuting Hamiltonians."  He has a knack for writing in a style that, while not rigorous, allows the reader to fill in all rigorous details, and at the same time communicates high excitement.

His textbook Introduction to Commutative Algebra, written with Macdonald, is like a volume of poetry.  I would guess (from internal stylistic evidence) that it was mostly written by Macdonald, but it's all great.

Answer (score 16):

Well, for me **Hartshorne** was really the window into the brave new world — and yes, it fits several items from 'acceptable reasons'.

Though this prize should be shared with everyone else who was creating abstract algebraic geometry and scheme theory in the past century or so (I spare you the history, you already know it :) )

Answer (score 16):

In my opinion Atiyah's paper "vector bundles over an elliptic curve" is a gem that everyone interested in algebraic geometry should read.

Answer (score 16):

Some of my favourite authors are Serre, Mumford, Milnor, Fulton and Neukirch. These names are rather mainstream, I guess. But the most beautiful analysis textbook I ever read must be ["Analysis now"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387967885), by Gert Pedersen. Alas, the book is not as well known as it should be.

Answer (score 15):

One of my all-time favorites for rigour and clarity:

Vistoli's Notes on [Descent](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf).

Comment: It is incredible how Vistoli manages to make so clear a subject which is so abstract and notationally heavy. A masterpiece of mathematical writing.

Answer (score 15):

1. Milne's entire set of notes (algebraic number theory, class field theory, algebraic groups, complex multiplication, modular functions and modular forms, etc.), articles (abelian varieties, Jacobian varieties, Shimura Varieties, Tannakian Categories, etc.) and books (Elliptic Curves, Arithmetic Duality Theorems, Etale Cohomology etc.), available at [www.jmilne.org/math/](http://www.jmilne.org/math/). They are indispensable for anyone who wishes to learn the fundamental concepts in arithmetic geometry. The Storrs lectures on Abelian Varieties and Jacobian Varieties are clear, succinct and give great references throughout. His notes on 'Class Field Theory' are superbly written. 'Etale Cohomology' is a standard reference for the subject, although I find his lecture notes on the same topic even more enjoyable. Finally, 'Arithmetic Duality Theorems' is quite possibly the only reference where one can find complete proofs of Tate's Duality Theorems as well as their generalizations using etale and flat cohomology.
2. Part 4 (particularly Chapter XX) of Lang's 'Algebra'. I may have learned (as little as I have) about homological algebra from Weibel or Gelfund-Manin as texts, but I always keep coming back to Lang's exposition. Not a lot of motivation, but it covers almost everything you need to know in a first course.

Comment: Copy pasted from a comment from the OP on another answer: Please split this into two (or more) answers. The point of having a big list with one answer per post is that it makes it easy to vote things up and down. If you post more than one answer per post, this advantage of being able to bubble answers up and down is lost.

Answer (score 15):

I'm shocked no one mentioned T.Y. Lam. He is perhaps the clearest expositor I've ever read, he motivates and gives history in every section, he fills his books with great examples and problems, and I have yet to find any errors. Indeed, his exercises are often finding counterexamples for errors in other published works, e.g. the following in *Lectures on Modules and Rings*:

In a ring theory text, the following statement appeared: "If $0\rightarrow C\rightarrow Q\rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$ is exact with $C$ and $Q$ finitely generated then $P$ is finitely presented" Give a counterexample.

Comment: Gian-Carlo Rota had a very nice review of one of Lam's books. Can anyone find it in free access?

Comment: I do recall Rota saying some nice things about Lam and A First Course in Noncommutative Rings in Indiscrete Thoughts, 242-244. I managed to find a snippet online by googling "professor neanderthal rota" (try it). 

Answer (score 15):

Riemann's paper, "On the number of primes less than a given magnitude," is the reason why I decided  to study mathematics (at the graduate level and beyond).  I read the paper as an undergraduate and I was very impressed by the techniques that Riemann used to study the properties of the prime counting function.  In particular, I was blown away by Riemann's use of complex analysis, Fourier analysis, and asymptotic analysis to study a problem in number theory, which I thought was a distant area of mathematics.  This paper is truly a work of art and is less than 10 pages.

Answer (score 13):

I've always really enjoyed the papers by Graeme Segal. They are short and I often feel like they have been distilled down into the essence of what is important. I keep going back to them and extracting new nuggets of beauty.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example that you would say is quintessential Graeme Segal?

Answer (score 13):

The American Mathematical Society awards the Leroy P. Steele Prize, in part for recognition of mathematical exposition:

The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Lifetime Achievement
The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Mathematical Exposition
The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Seminal Contribution to Research

These prizes were established in 1970 in honor of George David Birkhoff, William Fogg Osgood, and William Caspar Graustein, and are endowed under the terms of a bequest from Leroy P. Steele. From 1970 to 1976 one or more prizes were awarded each year for outstanding published mathematical research; most favorable consideration was given to papers distinguished for their exposition and covering broad areas of mathematics. In 1977 the Council of the AMS modified the terms under which the prizes are awarded. Since then, up to three prizes have been awarded each year in the following categories: (1) for the cumulative influence of the total mathematical work of the recipient, high level of research over a period of time, particular influence on the development of a field, and influence on mathematics through Ph.D. students; (2) for a book or substantial survey or expository-research paper; (3) for a paper, whether recent or not, that has proved to be of fundamental or lasting importance in its field, or a model of important research. In 1993, the Council formalized the three categories of the prize by naming each of them: (1) The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Lifetime Achievement; (2) The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Mathematical Exposition; and (3) The Leroy P. Steele Prize for Seminal Contribution to Research.  Each of these three US$5,000 prizes is awarded annually.

The winners in the area of Mathematical Exposition, including prizes for specific books are listed here:

http://www.ams.org/prizes/steele-prize.html

Comment: a more direct link: http://www.ams.org/profession/prizes-awards/pabrowse?purl=steele-prize?ME

Answer (score 12):

John Hubbard's book on Teichmuller theory is clear, beautiful, inspiring, and (amazingly) essentially self-contained.  He has a fantastic ability to take very technical and difficult results and make them seem clear and natural.

Bill Thurston wrote a preface for it which can be read here :

http://matrixeditions.com/Thurstonforeword.html

The money quote : "I only wish that I had had access to a source of this caliber much earlier in my career."

Comment: That forward is worthwhile just for this quote: "Mathematics is a paradoxical, elusive subject,  with the habit of appearing clear and straightforward, then zooming away and leaving us stranded in a blank haze."  Yeah, I can relate to that.

Answer (score 11):

Lazarsfeld's book *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry* seems to fit the category ``Anyone in my field who hasn't read this paper has led an impoverished existence.''

I agree with Scott on `anything Serre.' His FAC and GAGA are gems; they will change your life.

Answer (score 11):

From more introductory texts, some of the most well-written textbooks I came across are

- Visual complex analysis, by Tristan Needham
- Differential equations, by Blanchard, Devaney, and Hall

Comment: Please split this into two answers. The point of having a big list with one answer per post is that it makes it easy to vote things up and down. If you post more than one answer per post, this advantage of being able to bubble answers up and down is lost.

Answer (score 11):

*Toric Varieties*, about to be published by Cox, Little and Schenck is an unmeasurable amount of joy. It is impossible to get tired of it. Everything is well-bounded and it made me learn as much Algebraic Geometry as Toric Geometry itself. Its introductory sections to Algebraic Geometry before it develops the theory and shows you how to compute examples made me learn more than any dry full theoretic book in Algebraic Geometry. Definitely the best book I have read in two years.

Available at [Cox's website](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/%7Edac/toric.html) (Wayback Machine: [July 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110726075749/https://www.cs.amherst.edu/%7Edac/toric.html), [August 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110809142709/https://www.cs.amherst.edu/%7Edac/toric.html), [July 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150718021023/https://www.cs.amherst.edu/%7Edac/toric.html))

Comment: Unfortunately, "Toric Varieties" is no longer available at Cox's website, as it has been published by AMS.

Comment: It was when I posted this :)

Answer (score 11):

I think Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534950973) deserves a mention. It is incredibly clear, full of valuable examples, and an absolute classic. I can't think of a better book for a mathematician who's interested in theoretical computer science. It also seems to serve computer scientists without a great deal of mathematical background by providing an introduction to proofs at the beginning. My favorite part: all theorems come with "Proof Idea" first and then proof after that. This helps the computer scientists who are not that familiar with proofs, but it's also great for a mathematician to get the main idea of the proof, fill in the blanks themselves, and then move on to the next result.

Answer (score 10):

Probably the book(s) that most captivated me to study numerical analysis are the two by Forman Acton: "Numerical Methods That (usually) Work" and "Real Computing Made Real". The pithy and practical advice contained in both instilled in me the habits of trying to figure out just how structured the givens of a problem may be, among other things.

Answer (score 10):

Donaldson and Kronheimer's "Geometry of 4-manifolds" - masters of the subject, they have a knack of explaining the crux of a difficult theorem in a concise and elegant way, and gauge theory has a lot of difficult theorems. After many years of reading, it still has new surprises.

Comment: Almost all of Donaldson's paper are a delight to read...

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised I haven't seen Serge Lang. Some complain that he is too terse, but I really enjoy his style. Often times when i grab several books from the library on the same subject, it will be Lang's book I end up using the most. As for a single piece of writing, I think Lang's Algebra will do.

Answer (score 10):

Harris and Fulton Representation theory is a nice book. Linear algebraic groups of Jim  Humphreys is also very good one. On Riemann Surface the book of  Forster's is really very good one.

Comment: I second Fulton–Harris.

Answer (score 8):

Another paper that I really like, because it makes a lot of things that are muddled in the literature very clear, is Sawin's [Quantum Groups at Roots of Unity and Modularity](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308281).  In particular the lesson to learn is that if it takes you a while to sort through which papers use which conventions or to find all the relevant constants attached to Lie algebras, then you really owe it to your readers to put that information in your paper where it's easy to find (preferably in a table).

Answer (score 8):

The survey paper *[Hilbert's Tenth Problem over rings of number-theoretic interest](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf)* by Bjorn Poonen (my advisor) is one of my favorites. He has several survey papers on his web page. My first year of grad school I read many of these and decided I wanted to work with him, so in a sense this paper did `change my life'.

In general Bjorn's writing is extremely clear and I have tried to model my own writing on his.

Answer (score 8):

books I enjoyed very much:
Mumford "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface";
Mumford "Curves and their Jacobians";
Mumford "Basics of Torus Embeddings; Examples of the Theory": Chapter 1 in "Smooth Compactification of Locally Symmetric Varieties";
Koblitz "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms"; Deligne SGA 4 1/2

In general I found Bourbaki-seminar texts often very helpfull and readable. Unfortunately many of the newer issues seem not to be free available on the web.

Comment: Geometric invariant theory is also a perfect book. I think it isthe best of Mumford.

Answer (score 8):

*Category Theory* by Steve Awodey (Oxford Logic Guides 49) is a very clear exposition of the subject.

And I know my students hate it, but I really like *The Way of Analysis* by Robert Strichartz.

Comment: Personally, I think Mac Lane's Categories for the Working Mathematician is a much better introduction to category theory.

Comment: Daniel, clearly the aims and audiences differ. Awodey was Mac Lane's last PhD advisee, and speaks well of Mac Lane's book (as so many of us who grew up on Mac Lane do), but he set out to write something suitable for different students. 

Answer (score 8):

"A panoramic view of Riemannian Geometry" by M. Berger is an example of excellent mathematical writing to my taste. This book is great to learn what are the questions of interest in the field, and what are the main results. Although you will not find detailed proofs of the results, the main ideas are often explained in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 8):

I'm astonished that nobody has mentioned I. G. Macdonald's classic [Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials](http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~duchamp/Books&more/Macdonald/%5BI._G._Macdonald%5D_Symmetric_Functions_and_Hall_Pol%28BookFi.org%29.pdf). It is more than 50 years old but fun to read, compact, self-contained, elegant, deep.

Comment: So much of Macdonald is a pleasure to read.  I wish I could get my hands now on his *Spherical functions on a group of $p$-adic type*; I read this book as a graduate student and have only gradually appreciated how much is in it.  (Plus, the poor man goes through life and afterlife being called MacDonald, EIEIO.)

Answer (score 8):

A useful example of good writing style is how Thurston introduces his geometrization conjecture in

*W. P. Thurston. [Three dimensional manifolds, Kleinian groups and hyperbolic geometry](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1982-15003-0). Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.), 6(3):357–381, 1982.*

Here is the excerpt:

> Three-manifolds are greatly more complicated than surfaces, and I think it is fair to say that until recently there was little reason to expect any analogous theory for manifolds of dimension 3 (or more)—except perhaps for the fact that so many 3-manifolds are beautiful.  The situation has changed, so that I feel fairly confident in proposing the
>
> 1.1. CONJECTURE.  *The interior of every compact 3-manifold has a canonical decomposition into pieces which have geometric structures.*
>
> In §2, I will describe some theorems which support the conjecture, but first some explanation of its meaning is in order.

To state the conjecture formally, Thurston would have had to first define his 8 geometries. Instead, he wisely spends the introduction to explain where the conjecture comes from, in particular mentioning that it would imply the Poincaré conjecture. He introduces the now famous 8 geometries in the subsequent pages, along with illuminating examples and figures. All in all, a deep technical conjecture that would take pages to state formally becomes an enjoyable read even for the non-expert.

This example teaches us how one can provide a rough overview of a result before getting to the technical details.

Answer (score 7):

1. The book "Linear Algebra" by Greub; I've always thought his writing here was gorgeous, if a bit Spartan.
2. Most of John Stillwell's books.

Answer (score 7):

Simon Donaldson - Riemann Surfaces
Great writing, deep understanding. I believe that noone have mentioned it because this topic is older than the book.

Answer (score 7):

I think I went through all questions without seeing Bourbaki. I think that his *Algèbre Commutative* is simply a dream to read; every time I open it, I found myself keeping on reading it about perfectly useless subjects (compared to what I was looking for) just for the pleasure, as I was used to do as a kid with some of my parents' books. The same happens to me with *Topologie Générale*

Besides this, I must also add two litte gems by John Tate, namely his *Rigid Analytic Spaces* and a small paper where he studies residues on curves in an adelic language, *Residues of differentials on Curves*, Ann. Sci. Ecole Norm. Sup. (1968).

Answer (score 7):

Anything and everything (including papers) by Marty Isaacs. I am more familiar with his "Finite Group Theory" book, but from the little I have seen, the same holds for his "Algebra" textbook. Of course, his book on Character Theory is the canonical text in that area.

The power of Isaacs' writing lies primarily in the clarity of his arguments. You are never left wondering where a certain bit came from, and he manages that without over-repeating himself, or over-explaining.

Then it's the content itself. In the first 70 pages of his FGT book, one already learns "exotic" stuff like the Chermak-Delgado measure, and the Theorems of Horosevskii, Lucchini, and Zenkov.

Another merit of his books is his choice of exercises. He really can't be commended enough on this. All are carefully chosen to supplement and strengthen the material presented in a flawless way.

A huge bonus is that nearly all arguments presented are his, and are as close to "from first principles" as possible.

Comment: Isaacs' lovely books definitely deserve to be higher up on this list.

Answer (score 7):

The book "Infinite loop spaces" by J.F. Adams is one of my favorite mathematical texts. He introduces the subject with enough technicality to make it rigorous, but not so much that one loses sight of the forest for the trees. The added humor also makes it a delight to read.

Comment: Adams is a pleasure to read in general.  I keep coming back to the beautiful "Lectures on exceptional Lie groups."

Answer (score 6):

This paper changed my life:

Vaughan Jones, "Hecke algebra representations of braid groups and link polynomials"

Answer (score 6):

Kontsevich's 1994 paper "Homological Algebra of Mirror Symmetry" has been very inspiring to me. It is full of tantalizing ideas and speculations, and brings so many different aspects of mathematics (and physics!) together into one beautiful tapestry.

Comment: I find that's true of most of Kontsevich's papers.

Answer (score 6):

Lou Kauffman's book "On Knots" inspired me to become a topologist. It conveys the feel of the way topologists think with copious hand-drawn pictures. It also gets into deep waters without losing a playful touch. It would actually be nice to have a similar book that covers the recent developments in knot theory as well.

Answer (score 6):

Steven Strogatz's "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" book is written in a manner that almost allows one to kick back in a recliner and enjoy.  The style is one that draws one into the material on nonlinear ODEs... probably the best undergrad text book that I used.

Answer (score 6):

Poincaré's `[Sur les solutions périodiques et le principe de moindre action](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k30799/f915.item)'.

in *Comptes Rendus des Séances de l'Académie des Sciences*, t. 123, p 915-918, 1896

This paper humbled me. It made me realize how much the founders of the subject(s) I work in  really knew, and how far ahead they could see. I am in awe of how Poincaré could give such a detailed trip report of his investigations without the formal language we use today being in place.  (In many ways, formal language often gets in the way.) In these 2 and a half pages, Poincaré does most everything I did in a 13 page paper 102 years later. He does it more clearly and elegantly.

Answer (score 5):

Actually a book that ended up changing my life:
Kaczynski, Mischaikow, Mrozek: Computational Homology

I read it while working on my master's thesis in computational homological algebra, in order to see what they had to say about efficient implementations of simplicial homology.

After reading it, I first realized that algebraic topology has applications far outside what I had seen thus far - and now, a doctorate later, I'm active in the field of Applied Algebraic Topology and Topological Data Analysis.

I'm not certain I'd peg it for *great writing* as such, but the criteria above *did* state "changed my life".

Answer (score 5):

I loved reading Zelevinsky's 'Representations of finite classical groups'. It gave a totally different perspective to everything that I knew before about representation theory.

Answer (score 5):

I'll mention WL Burke's "Applied Differential Geometry." It's written for physicists, it will not be to the liking of the majority of mathematicians, but it changed this engineer's view of geometric methods forever.

The book changed the direction of my research because it presented a point of view that is not readily accessible if you follow the control and optimization literature. Becoming familiar with the differential geometry literature is an investment that a controls person is unlikely to make without a general idea of where the complete set of tools leads to. In this sense, the mathematics literature can present an obstacle. Burke's exposition is intuitive, though quite informal, and led me to read Spivak, Milnor, and other books, some mentioned here, which I would not have read if I had started with the math literature.

Answer (score 5):

Lam's *Serre's Problem on Projective Modules*. It contains everything: The big picture, the proof details, interesting techniques and the links between different methods. I wish more books were like this.

Answer (score 4):

1. "Differential calculus on Normed Linear Banach Spaces" by Prof.Kalyan Mukherjee

   This book gave me a very hands-on explorable window into the world of manifolds and Lie groups. Like it shows explicit calculations of derivative of matrix multiplication and determinant maps and also about computing tangents to curves inside Lie groups.
2. "Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields" by Gregory Naber.  (2 Volumes)

   Its an exciting book which got me motivated into topology when it explained to me very simply the Heegard decomposition of S^3 and hence Hopf Fibration and how that relates to Dirac Monopoles! Before I read this book I had no clue that I would find mathematics exciting. Especially this revived my childhood interest in geometry.

   Naber's are books that changed my career decision.
3. "Global Calculus" by S.Ramanan  (in the AMS series)

   This is a hard book to read initially but it excites the reader a lot and it was great to read alongside when Prof.Ramanan taught me topology and differential geometry. Anyway Prof.S.Ramanan is a great expositor. He could teach topics like modular forms and algebraic curves to a bunch of undergrads in their first complex analysis course in Chennai Mathematical Institute (CMI), India! He really pushes up the possible limits of exposition.

   Prof.S.Ramanan's lectures in my alma mater CMI, affected my career choices almost as much as Naber's books did.
4. "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak

   Its treatment of Fubini's theorem and related issues are great.
5. The writings on group theory by a college senior of mine called Vipul.
   His wiki "groupprops" is an amazing repository on finite group theory.

   His extensive efforts into mathematical writing also inspired me into periodically LaTex-ing up interesting things in mathematics as I learn.

Can anyone here tell about nice expository writings on topics like Gromov-Witten theory or Reshetkhin-Turaev and Rozansky-Khovanov stuff and how these relate to QFT? Something which shows a lot of examples and may be also explicit calculations.

Most sources on Quantum Groups that I have tried looking at start off a bit harshly for the newcomer. I would be greatly interested to read of "great mathematical writing" in these areas.

Comment: I want to vote up because of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, but I don't want to vote up (1)-(3) since I've never read them. So I leave this comment instead.

Answer (score 4):

I an algebraic geometer, so the book I'm going to propose is about as far from my subject as it can be. Still I think that [Steele's book on stochastic calculus](https://www.amazon.de/Stochastic-Calculus-Financial-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0387950168/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1279114527&sr=8-1) is one of the best written mathematical books I know. It really makes you enjoy probability, starting from the simplest examples of random walks and building a lot of theory, like martingales, Brownian motion and Ito's integral. I almost wanted to change my subject when I was reading it! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Mathematical logic has at least a couple of great writers. The canonical example is Bruno Poizat, especially the French originals; I would put Hodges in the same league. Both are emphatically not concise writers (at least in their most famous books). Their use of the full capabilities of language is very didactic, and often poetic. I greatly admire them both.

Comment: Poizat's book is wonderful (except for some of its jokes), with a definitely personal insight to its topic. I admire his treatment of Gödel's incompleteness where he replaces Gödel's coding by an interpretation of finite sets within Peano arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone studying Stable Homotopy Theory, a fantastic text is Doug Ravenel's "green book" (although the second edition is red) *Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Theory*

Not only is this book full of useful results for those in the field (making it an incredible reference for those starting out), it is also written in a very clear style and it's completely self-contained. I cannot think of a better book on how to do computation in homotopy theory. This definitely fits under "I wish someone had told me about this when I was younger" and "anyone in my field who hasn't read this is leading an impoverished existence"

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the papers on $A_\infty$-structures by Bernhard Keller are extremely well written: they provide the reader with an overview of the state of the art of research in the topic(s), applications and even understandable proofs. I suggest in particular

[*A-infinity algebras, modules and functor categories*](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/ainffun.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Imre Lakatos: "Proofs and Refutations.  The logic of mathematical discovery" is a fantastic read!

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it "mathematical writing" though. It talks *about* mathematics from a certain philosophical POV and with historical examples, and the fictional classroom setting is engaging, but for the most part it's not mathematics. I find the final exposition of the actual proof of Euler's formula fairly turgid.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find  Disquisitiones Arithmeticae listed as an answer, and find this strange. (It has been translated from the Latin). The book is a delight to read, and the proofs always seem to be exactly the right ones.

Comment: So you feel that its proof of quadratic reciprocity is exactly the right one?

Comment: @keith--I guess not, though it has its adherents on this site--I think Lemmermeyer speaks well of it. Isn't this the proof that essentially calculates K_2(Z)?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason the proof is useful, but I'd never count it as the first (or second or third) proof worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

[Hugo Steinhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Steinhaus)' book "Mathematical Kaleidoscope"

Answer (score 3):

Harder's Algebraic Geometry 1 is a beautiful example of explaining why an abstract subject makes sense.  The book has a conversational style without wasting words, and focuses on providing intuition for the subject.

When I get disheartened, this is the book I turn to for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

‘[Galois Cohomology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1974-3_4)’ by Larry Washington in [Cornell–Silverman–Stevens - Modular forms and Fermat's last theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1974-3) is my one stop reference for the eponymous topic. In about twenty pages (and with minimal prerequisites), he introduces Galois cohomology groups, explains Tate Local Duality Theorem and Euler Characteristic, shows the connection between extensions, deformation and cohomology groups, introduces generalized Selmer groups and proves a result that appears in Wiles' proof. Along the way, he also fully explains the Poitou-Tate nine-term exact sequence! Terrific stuff.

Answer (score 2):

*I wish someone had told me about this paper when I was younger.*

I have had this feeling a few times.  For example:
Gillman & Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions*.

Answer (score 2):

I wish someone had told me about this book when I was younger: 
A.I. Mal'cev, Algorithms and Recursive Functions.

The exposition is simple, thought provoking and rigorous. You are teased to delve into many strains when reading it.

Answer (score 2):

Weil's "Basic Number Theory" is my favorite book. Norbert Schappacher once said "If you learn number theory from this book, you will never forget it."

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic Functions and Projective Curves by David M. Goldschmidt; October 2000

Beautiful proofs; Chapter 6 (Zeta Functions), 6.3 Riemann Hypothesis, nice mathematics.

Anyone in David's field who has not at least sampled this book is leading an impoverished existence.

Falco

Comment: Yes it is a great book, especially the chapter that contains embedding to projective space

Answer (score 1):

I want to mention two papers (related).

- The very famous [Complex analytic connections in fibre bundles](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-01/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5.pdf) by Michael Atiyah.
- The not so famous [The Atiyah bundle and connections on a principal bundle](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/120/03/0299-0316) by Indranil Biswas.

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-365-h) by Jeff Cheeger and David Ebin.

Why it is great:

> - ... this is a wonderful book, full of fundamental techniques and ideas. (Robert L. Bryant)
> - Cheeger and Ebin's book is a truly important classic monograph in Riemannian geometry, with great continuing relevance. (Rafe Mazzeo)

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised nobody has recommend the two-volume series *The Chauvenet Papers* printed by the MAA.

The work is a collection of prize-winning expository papers on mid-to-advanced undergraduate topics in mathematics; I have read most of them myself and would say they are invaluable surveys into various topics of mathematics (examples include broad areas such as harmonic analysis or the history between mathematics and logic, problem-specific articles such as one on Hilbert's 10th problem, and more miscellaneous works like Zalcman's "Real proofs of complex theorems (and vice-versa).")

Answer (score 0):

despite the numerous replies here is masterpiece yet to be mentioned :

Alain Connes'  [**Noncommutative Geometry**](https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/book94bigpdf.pdf)

This is a most brilliant introduction and overview of many modern aspects in all of the areas

- Analysis (in particular algebraic)
- Geometry (in particular algebraic, non commutative and infinite dimensional)
- Topology (in particular algebraic and analytic)
- Statistical Physics and Quantum Theory

It is simply just *perfect* in every aspect - the pedagogical style, graphical design and illustrations, historical side notes .... but most of all ...
***the originality of the mathematical thought!***