# Further reading in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I recently finished reading W. Fulton's "Algebraic Curves" and also attended a lecture series on moduli spaces and am interested in learning about them as well. I looked for a few books to self learn more but couldn't find anything that was reader friendly.
Please suggest some topics for further reading and some resource that I can read. I am also familiar with representation theory, and basic Lie theory, so some topic on the intersection of these subjects is also fine.

Thanks already!

Comment: Related: [A learning roadmap for algebraic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1291). In particular, *Moduli of Curves* by Harris and Morrison was mentioned by a couple of people. See also [What should be learned in a first serious schemes course?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28496) and [Undergraduate roadmap to algebraic geometry?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35288)

Answer (score 7):

You might like the survey paper of Peter Newstead, *Geometric Invariant Theory*, 2006, CIMAT, Guanajuato.

Answer (score 6):

Mukai's "Introduction to invariants and moduli" is a lovely book: https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316257074

Answer (score 1):

I think that the basics for algebraic geometry are in R. Hartshorne's book *Algebraic Geometry*

*Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit Spaces* by Peter Newstead is very good for an introduction to moduli spaces.

You can then go further if you are interested in sheaves with *The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves* by  D. Huybrechts and M. Lehn