# Introductions to modern algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if people have any feelings on the pros and cons of various introductions to algebraic geometry (among the contenders would be Ravi Vakil's notes, Hartshorne, Mumford, Harris, Eisenbud-Harris, and I am sure many others I am not aware of).

Comment: Take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2446/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne