# references about the state of algebraic geometry between 1930 and 1955?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview

I asked the question a few weeks ago in another form, but did not have any answers nor comments. So I will try again another way: could you recommend bibliography concerning the state of algebraic geometry in the pre-Grothendieck period? From what I understood, at least two schools where prominent: Weil's approach, and Zariski's approach.

I would like to understand the differences between those approaches (and maybe others?).

Any key articles, or history of mathematics books, that could help understanding that?

Comment: Not particularly original, but Dieudonné's *History of Algebraic Geometry* (Springer) has a chapter about that period.

Comment: Yes thank you, I knew that, but I was looking for alternative references on the subject.

Comment: In my answer to the linked question, I recommended some ICM talks by the experts themselves, especially in 1954.https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31650/modern-algebraic-geometry-vs-classical-algebraic-geometry

Comment: @roy smith : thank you, this conversation is full of interesting things on historical perspectives about alg geometry. Nevertheless, I havn't found the ICM lectures you mentioned. The link you provide isn't working. Are these lectures freely available on internet ?

Comment: yes my link is broken, but this was pointed out in a comment where there is a valid link I believe.

Comment: try this link for volume 3, https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1954.3/ICM1954.3.ocr.pdf. especially pages 497, 550 of the alg geom symposium beginning on page 447. also weyl's talk in volume 1, page 161.

Comment: @roy smith : thank you, these proceedings contain exactly what I was looking for !