# Preparation for GIT (Geometric Invariant Theory)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, geometric-invariant-theory

I am trying to read Mumford's *Geometric Invariant Theory*, however, I find my knowledge in algebraic geometry is inadequate. My knowledge is at the level of  Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. Mumford cites a lot of results from EGA and SGA, but I cannot read French. Therefore, I want to ask:

> **What should I read if I want to read GIT?**

I should mention that most of my knowledge is in differential geometry. I want to read Mumford's work to understand stable bundles and moment maps from another perspective; different from differential geometry.

> **Any suggestions for alternatives to Mumford's work will also be acceptable.**

Comment: Mumford has written a survey *Stability of projective varieties* in l'Enseignement Mathématique, Vol.23 (1977), which is much more accessible than his book. It is freely accessible on the web.

Comment: Is there a specific part of GIT you’re having trouble with?

Comment: @SamirCanning I just find too many unfamiliar terms and theorems. For example, Mumford used "Chevalley's Criterion" in page 6,(4). His reference is EGA ch. 4,14.4 which is written in French. I have never heard such a theorem. Also there are two many terms with prefix "Geometrically" such as geometrically injective, which means being injective on geometrcal points, but I am unfamiliar with such terms. I know I am very weak in algebraic geometry, so I want to know how to fill the gap. Anyway, thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before I started reading/referencing *Geometric Invariant Theory* by Mumford, Fogarty, Kirwan I read Dolgachev's book *Lectures on Invariant Theory*.  I also like Peter Newstead's book *Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit Spaces*.  Given your stated interest, these treatments might be sufficient.  Even if they are not, you should be able to read them after going through Hartshorne and then I would guess GIT will be "easier" to read (the technicality will still be the same, but your intuition will be better).

Addendum (given OP's comment):  As far as a prerequisite for GIT itself, I don't know (beyond Hartshorne).  I think when you come across a concept or term you are unfamiliar with you need to just "bite the bullet" and find a reference for that definition/concept and think about the concept.  So you can use EGA/SGA as referenced directly in GIT or you can perhaps find what you need in the [StacksProject](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/) (see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207388/12218) about the pros/cons of this).  But if you have first read, say Dolgachev's notes, then when you are trying to put together these new ideas into a coherent whole it will be easier since you will have some sense of what the bigger picture looks like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try to read these books for a better intuituion. However I am also looking for a book which can serve a prerequisite of Mumford's book. Does there exist such a book?

Comment: @ZetaW I added an addendum that attempts to answer your comment.  Others on MO probably can speak to this better than I.

Comment: Nolan R. Wallach has a new book "Geometric Invariant Theory Over the Real and Complex Numbers" that should be quite accessible.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that Kirwan's thesis "Topology of quotients in symplectic and algebraic geometry" hasn't been mentioned yet, as a place to see GIT in a rather differential-geometric perspective. Of course, Kirwan is coauthor on the 3rd edition of GIT.