English Versions of EGA and SGA
As a non-French speaker, does anyone have any English translations of EGA and SGA?  If you citing them would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3041 for a related question. It is doubtful that full English translations of these voluminous texts exist. Two standard responses are: mathematical French is not that hard to learn if you already read mathematical English; automatic translation tools do a decent job of translating any text you input to them.

See projects for EGA and for SGA.

I do not know if this is helpful, but apparently you can translate math papers for free using the following link (you need to upload the file yourself first):
http://aistudio.google.com/app/prompts/new_chat
I had been using this and ChatGPT for translating Asterique papers from Numdam in the past year. The results are not perfect but a good starting point for arithmetic geometry papers.
Note for old papers without OCR you may need to having OCR done first.
(Do not infer from this I am still active in professional mathematics)
