# Approachable French masters

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list, reading-list, textbook-recommendation

Similar to [this topic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28268/do-you-read-the-masters), what are the easiest foundational French texts for someone learning the language? My intuition would be Cauchy and Lebesgue, but I have no idea where to start or which of their works are readily available.

Comment: As for the texts themselves, here is a useful link (complete works) : http://math-doc.ujf-grenoble.fr/OEUVRES/  .(

Comment: @js Cool, I had no idea!

Comment: In what fields of mathematics are you interested ?

Comment: @Lierre , My current work is in math bio, but I also have an interest in operator theory. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mention Lebesgue, I would recommend the following two classics, which build on his lectures at the Collège de France :

*[Leçons sur l'intégration](http://archive.org/stream/leonssurlintgra00lebegoog#page/n8/mode/2up)*

*[Leçons sur les séries trigonométriques](http://archive.org/stream/leonssurlessrie01lebegoog#page/n6/mode/2up)*

Another suggestions : *Topologie générale* by Bourbaki, and *Théorie des distrbutions* by Laurent Schwartz.

Comment: It's strange to mention Laurent Schwartz's Théorie des distributions and Bourbaki in the same sentence. I found Schwartz very readable with lots of useful and interesting material, but never managed to read much of Bourbaki before becoming bored. Have a look at Schwartz's first article on distributions to get a feeling for how readable he writes: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AUG/AUG_1945__21_/AUG_1945__21__57_0/AUG_1945__21__57_0.pdf

Comment: @Thomas : It may depend on which Bourbaki book you chose to read. Personnally I think that Topologie générale is a masterpiece, but some people may have different taste.

Answer (score 21):

The canonical excellent French author is Serre (his books are also quite easy to find) -- Cours d'Arithmetique has some analytic content, if you like that sort of thing, as you say you do...

Comment: Just for the purpose of uniqueness: this Serre is Jean-Pierre Serre

Comment: Yes. Of course @Denis Serre has some pretty nice books himself (available in both languages, for ease of learning!)

Comment: I have never really learnt to appreciate Serre's writing style. Too condensed and impersonal for my taste.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for French classics, I would recommend Darboux's *Théorie générale des surfaces* There is a lot of analysis there. In fact the text is mostly about the interplay between differential equations and differential geometry. Goursat's *Leçons d'analyse* are also quite nice. I read somewhere that Bourbaki started as a rejection to this text, but that only makes it more interesting. I also like Appell and Goursat's *Théorie des fonctions algébriques et leurs intégrales*. Appell's books on mechanics are really nice as well.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you have a look at Bourbaki's talks [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB/) as they range quite a few topics, are generally short enough, are often in french, and are regularly from masters. Of course, you'll find other interesting collections on the same website.

Comment: "Page not found" :-(

Comment: I updated my link

Comment: Julien Puydt, thank you. To many, these Séminaire Bourbaki volumes were highly important, e.g. about Lie Algebras.

Answer (score 6):

Roger Godement. His courses (in analysis, differential geometry, algebra, etc.) are
magnificient.

Answer (score 4):

Actually Borel wrote a series of very nice little books, around 1900's. One of them is called "Sur les series de Taylor a coefficient positive". It has some very nice theorem, many of which are forgotten at this day; it reads like a beautifully written paper that just came out.

Also, Paul Levy. He has an exceedingly beautiful writting style. His 7 volume collected works should be available in a math library.

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy's *Cours d'Analyse* is beautifully written, and good for the "analytically inclined". His treatment of infinitesimals is very interesting, and it contains the famous "mistaken proof" that a limit of continuous functions is continuous.  There's a CUP reprint, and it is online [here](http://archive.org/details/coursdanalysede00caucgoog)

Answer (score 3):

Fourier's *Théorie analytique de la chaleur* is available online [here](http://archive.org/stream/thorieanalytiqu00fourgoog#page/n11/mode/2up). As an advantage, the English version *The Analytical Theory of Heat* is available [here](http://archive.org/stream/analyticaltheor00fourgoog#page/n6/mode/2up).

> Do not forget François-Marie Arouet de **Voltaire**, **Jules** Gabriel **Verne**, **Victor**-Marie **Hugo**, **Antoine** de **Saint-Exupéry**, **Jean-Paul** Charles Aymard **Sartre**, ... :-)

Comment: Et Balzac ? Et Stendhal ?

Comment: ... Émile François Zola, Gustave Flaubert... !!! 

Comment: I think on the contrary that it is urgent to forget the morally repugnant Sartre and his verbal diarrhoea...

Answer (score 3):

For the *really* analytically inclined :), while I have not finished reading it myself, I have been told by multiple of my French colleagues that Leray's [original paper on Navier-Stokes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02547354) has interesting mathematics and quite penetrable language.

Comment: If you don't want to pay Springer 35 Euros, Leray's paper is available here http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdh/Leray.pdf (retypeset) and here http://www.cmi.univ-mrs.fr/~gallouet/artbase.d/leray-ns.pdf (badly scanned)

Comment: Indeed, my first PDE course involved translating and presenting sections of this paper.  As I recall, none of the students nor the professor had French as a first, second, or even third language. 
It was a challenging but doable endeavour.  (Hint:  Chaleur is not the name of a professor.)
Gerhard "Ne Parle Vouz Francais Still" Paseman, 2012.06.11

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fit to properly judge the quality of the language, but I've always found Dixmier's papers very lucid (although mathematically demanding for this Bear Of Little Brain). Plus, one gets to see some of the theory of Von Neumann algebras at an interesting time. Looking on NUMDAM ought to yield several papers, including IIRC the paper on $C^k$ functional calculus for self-adjoins elements in $L^1$ of a nilpotent group.

Answer (score 1):

For operator theory, Dixmier seems to be a good option.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97976/approachable-french-masters/98105#98105