# Why is this theorem attributed to J.-P. Serre?

Tags: ho.history-overview, ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

Page $117$ of Atiyah, MacDonald's *[Introduction to Commutative Algebra](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HOASFid4x18C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* text has the following theorem. Let $P(M,t)$ denote the *[Poincare- series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%25E2%2580%2593Poincar%25C3%25A9_series)* of $M$.

- $\textbf{Theorem.}$ $\bigl(\mathsf{Hilbert-Serre}\bigr)$. $P(M,t)$ is a rational function in $t$ of the form $f(t)/\prod_{i=1}^{s} (1-t^{k_i})$, where $f(t) \in \mathbf{Z}[t]$.

This theorem appears in the section of the book called *Hilbert-Functions* (page 116), so one understands that it could have possibly been discovered by *Hilbert*.

- But why is the above theorem attributed to J.-P. [Serre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Serre)?  References about when Serre was credited to the above theorem would be helpful.

Comment: Probably, it is the theorem which is attributed to Serre.

Comment: Chandrasekhar, I think that Mariano was commenting on your word order,
but it's not a big deal. If you look at Serre's "Algèbre Locale Multiplicités", it's clear that he was well aware of Hilbert's work on Hilbert polynomials.

Comment: Question "Did Serre discover this fact independently?" is very funny. 

Comment: Donu, Thanks. If you could pose that as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.


Comment: @Mark: What's so funny Mark? I don't understand :(

Comment: Chandresekhar, the comment by Mariano does not say so explicitly, but what he meant is that the title should be: "Why is the following theorem attributed to Serre?" A theorem is attributed to its author, not the author to his or her theorem. A similar English error appears in your question. 

Comment: I don't remember having proved this theorem.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for making me understand the error. BTW, you too made a spelling error while typing my name :)

Comment: @Denis Serre: If the single name "Serre" is used, it's likely that the person is meant who was awarded with the fields medal and who proved so many fundamental theorems in a variety of mathematical disciplines. 

Comment: Small humour and the internet are pretty inmiscible sometimes!

Comment: @Mariano: Is it $\text{inmiscible}$ or $\mathsf{immiscible}$ ?


Comment: About *humour*: Mariano understood the humour in my post (I am Jean-Pierre's nephew, and very proud to have such a reknowned mathematician in my family), but apparently Ralph didn't. Whence Mariano's comment about whether humour is soluble in internet.

Comment: @Denis Serre: It's only because you are posting the same kind of comment as soon as the name "Serre" occurs. Compare for the one to  Igor's answer in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97976/approachable-french-masters/97977#97977. 

Comment: @Ralph, +1, you are the vivid memory of MO !

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: It is hard to explain. Question "Was Gauss-Manin connection  introduced independently by Gauss and Manin?" would be even funnier.  

Comment: @Mark: Hmmm, hearing Gauss-Mannin for the first time. Sorry if this question looks, funny. I only asked it because: It comes under Hilbert -functions section(in the book) and suddenly Serre's name pops out of nowhere.

Comment: Well, we all do like the guy...

Comment: Chandrasekhar, apologies for misspelling your name earlier. But continuing the grammatical theme of these comments, though, let me object that your highlighted question refers to "the following theorem", but there is no theorem following it! Shouldn't you refer at that point to the "preceding" theorem instead? Or just to "the theorem"...

Comment: @Joel: No problem. Yes I have made the edit accordingly. And if you find any more grammatical mistakes, then feel free to edit. Once the edit is done, I can review it and see what mistakes I have made. 

Comment: I went ahead and made the correction that I had meant...

Comment: Hilbert stated only the case where the degree of each generator of the polynomial ring is one. Atiyah-Macdonald allow any positive integer degrees. Perhaps Serre was the first one to state this generalization, though it takes no more work to prove than the original case. 

Comment: Serre o no Serre, esa es la pregunta...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what Atiyah-Macdonald were thinking, but I can tell you a theorem which is attributed to Serre (correctly, I think), and is relevant to this question.

Let $M$ be a finitely-generated graded $k[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ module. Let $H^0(M)$, $H^1(M)$, ..., $H^n(M)$ be the [local cohomology modules](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/huneke.pdf) of $M$ with respect to the maximal ideal $\langle x_0,\ldots, x_n \rangle$. These are graded modules which satisfy the following properties:

**Theorem:** For *all* integers $d$, the function
$$\dim M_d - \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \dim H^r(M)_d$$
is polynomial in $d$.

**Theorem (Serre vanishing)** For $d$ sufficiently large, $H^r(M)_d=0$.

So Serre vanishing separates Hilbert's theorem into two parts: A certain function is a polynomial for all $d$, and that function is equal to the Hilbert function for large $d$.

I'm presenting this using the language of commutative algebra, which I don't think is the language Serre used. In sheaf cohomology language, let $\mathcal{M}$ be the sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ corresponding to $M$ and let $\mathcal{H}^r(M) = \bigoplus_{d=-\infty}^{\infty} H^r(\mathbb{P}^{n-1}, \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{O}(-d))$. Then the relation between sheaf cohomology and local cohomology is that
$$\mathcal{H}^r(M) \cong H^{r+1}(M)$$
for $r \geq 1$ and there is a short exact sequence
$$0 \to H^0(M) \to M \to \mathcal{H}^0(M) \to H^1(M) \to 0.$$
In this language, Serre vanishing says that, for $d$ large, $\mathcal{H}^r(M)_d=0$ for $r>0$ and $M_d \cong \mathcal{H}^0(M)_d$; this is how the result is usually stated.
The first theorem in this language is that $\dim \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} (-1)^r \mathcal{H}^r(M)_d$ is a polynomial in $d$.

Comment: Minor quibble: according to your notation, it should be $\mathbb{P}^n$, since you start at $x_0$.