# Hurwitz, A. and R. Courant: Funktionentheorie , elliptic functions part

Tags: cv.complex-variables, elliptic-functions

Can some one suggests an English text covering that part of the book dealing with elliptic functions.
As i understand from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126420/functions-of-one-complex-variable-geometric-theory), there is no translation of the full book to English but maybe another text that present the subject in a similar manner or maybe this part was translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no English translation.
One book in English which covers most of the material 
is Akhiezer's book MR1054205. Another is Whittaker Watson.
Course of modern analysis.

EDIT. There are very many books covering the basic theory of elliptic functions,
old ones and new ones. But I don't know the book which could replace Hurwitz
(It is actually three books usually printed under one cover and called Hurwitz-Courant.) There is an excellent Russian translation (edited by Evgrafov), and an expanded modern German version by Rohrl. But there is no English version.

Comment: Do you know if he makes a similar presentation of elliptic functions as Hurwitz, A. and R. Courant ?   I understand there are different ways to treat this subject. Thanks.

Comment: It is not exactly similar but covers most of the material.

Comment: I would add to this the book by [Prasolov and Solovyev](http://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-170/).